# Run docker container with volume argument in AWS ECS as Task definition or Service

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-ecs, docker-gen

I am using [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/~/dockerfile/) docker image to proxying my other web application.
I can run this image using

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -e ENABLE_IPV6=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

command. Here `-v` option is mandatory if I run docker without `-v` 
ie

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -e ENABLE_IPV6=true jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

it gives the error:

```
ERROR: you need to share your Docker host socket with a volume at /tmp/docker.sock
Typically you should run your jwilder/nginx-proxy with: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro`
See the documentation at http://git.io/vZaGJ
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
```

Now my question is How can I provide this `-v` argument when I run this docker container using AWS ECS task definition or service.

Can I provide `-v` argument in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

The -v flag is shorthand for a bind mounted volume. [Here's the AWS documentation for that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide//task_definition_parameters.html#volumes). You can also do this in the AWS Management Console by adding a volume to the task def revision, then inside the container definition in the *Storage and Logging* section, mount that volume to the container.

**Bind mounts are not currently supported by AWS Fargate**. You will want to stick to ECS with EC2 hosts if you're set on using this nginx-proxy setup. **Edit**: this is no longer true, bind mounts are currently supported for Fargate (thanks @bobics)

A final caveat, bind mounted volumes only persist for the host on which they are mounted. So if you are running more than one EC2 instances as a host, you would have two divergent bind mounted volumes.

Comment: Not sure when this changed, but bind bounds are now supported with Fargate. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html
"Bind mount host volumes are supported when using either the EC2 or Fargate launch types."

Comment: I tried bind mounts on Fargate, and while they work, it doesn't look like they can be persisted. It doesn't allow me to set a sourcePath value in task definition config under volumes -> host.

Comment: Docker allows to mount the volumes at runtime using `-v` flag, but in ECS we have to define the mount point during container definition. How can I specify volume during `runTask`?